# Pybind11 automatic type conversions memory management

Tags: python, c++, pybind11

I am using Pybind11 to make a Python C++ extension module, and have the following code:

```cpp
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>
#include <string.h>
namespace py = pybind11;

int getLength(char* arg) {
   return strlen(arg);
}

PYBIND11_MODULE(example, m) {
    m.def("getLength", &getLength, "Get length using strlen", py::arg("arg"));
}
```

From the [type conversion documentations](https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/advanced/cast/overview.html#list-of-all-builtin-conversions), when I call `getLength` from Python, Pybind11 converts Python's `str` type to C++ `char*`. I assume that the memory for the new `char*` argument is allocated on the heap. My question is: does Pybind11 deallocate this on return, or I need to add `delete[] arg;` at the end of my function?

I know that if I were to change my function, to accept `py:str` (Python's string type), then manually converted it to C++ `char*` I would be responsible for (de)allocation. Does this hold for built in conversions too?

Does Pybind11 handle memory management of the results of automatic conversions, or do I need to do that?

Though I couldn't find the answer in the docs, I link it anyway: https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/advanced/cast/overview.html#list-of-all-builtin-conversions

Comment: First a nitpick -- shouldn't that be a const pointer? You certainly don't need to modify the string to find its length, and given that Python strings are immutable, you probably shouldn't try to modify it either.

Comment: I haven't really dug that deep into pybind, but the idea that you'd be responsible for freeing this seems counterintuitive. It would be an invitation for leaks, and probably a pessimization in many cases. I'd expect that (unless I explicitly make it clear I want to take ownership, etc.) that the parameters are only valid for the duration of the call. That would mean even if they were dynamically allocated, the wrapper would easily be able to clean them up as well. | It's a fairly modern C++ library, so I'd kinda expect it to not provide opportunities to leak things in the first place.

Comment: Finally, in most cases I wouldn't the string to be dynamically allocated for the call -- I'd rather expect to just get a pointer to the character array held by the python string object passed to the wrapper function.

Comment: @DanMašek Yes that makes sense. Thanks for the thoughts. It would be counterintuitive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case it will end up using the c-style string [type caster](https://github.com/pybind/pybind11/blob/master/include/pybind11/cast.h#L539), which in turn will instantiate a `std::string` [here](https://github.com/pybind/pybind11/blob/master/include/pybind11/cast.h#L404),   and the memory will be cleaned up when this `std::string`'s destructor is called. (unless it's an optimized small string which was allocated on the stack).

Although I am a little out of my depth here, it has to be a copy since python strings are (technically) immutable. But `pybind11` also allows conversions to a `std::string_view` which does not make a copy.

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer! It’s great that you linked the code so we can all see exactly what is going on!